# Check if animation is at the edge of screen in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

I am making an animation of a boats moving from one side of a windows form to the other side, but I have to notify the user when a boat touches the edge of the screen becasue he won. Anybody has any idea how to do this? 
This is what I  have so far:

```
  private void playerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if (PlayersActive[i])
            {
                Players[i].Move(randomNumber.Next(3,10));
                 //HERE IS WHERE I SHOULD CHECK TO SEE IF A BIKE HAS WON
                 //If player location is at the edge of the screen

            }
        }
        this.Invalidate();
    }
```

Code to move the boats:

```
    private void GameForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        // Set variables used to store logic to default values.
        int playersStillRacing = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            // Check to see if the current player is still racing.
            if (playersRacing[i])
            {
                // Incremement playersStillRacing.
                playersStillRacing++;

                // Set the playerPictureBox associated with this player to the new location
                //  the player is located at.
                playerPictureBoxes[i].Image = Players[i].Image;
                playerPictureBoxes[i].Left = Players[i].X;
                playerPictureBoxes[i].Top = Players[i].Y;


                g.DrawImage(playerPictureBoxes[i].Image, Players[i].X, Players[i].Y);

            }
         }

     }
```

Comment: it involves the length of your `bike`, how you render your `bike` (using some control directly or just draw it?)

Comment: To draw the bike I am using the paint event, then drawImage, because it is an image I resized from a picture of the internet.

Comment: How do you increase the Players[i].X? If you take the Players[i].X value and the width of the Players[i].Image then you'll be able to see if the image touches the end.

Comment: With the playertimer_tick, I invalidate the form so it can repaint itself with the new coordinates.

Comment: Ok if the following edit does not work. Then try to show the WHOLE code :D

Comment: It totally works!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: I am glad that i could help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this do the trick? I made some edits from the newest info you gave me

```
private void playerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (PlayersActive[i])
        {
            Players[i].Move(randomNumber.Next(3,10));

            // EDIT BELOW in the if statement!
            // if the edge of the picture touches the end of the screen.
            if (Players[i].X + Players[i].Image.Width >= this.Width)
                MessageBox.Show("Congrats! Player" + i.ToString() + "won!");

            //Players[i].X is the X cordinates(The length) from the left side of the winform.
            //Players[i].Image.Width is the width of the picture ofcourse :D.
            // if X cordinates + picture width is greater than or equal to screen width. YOU WON :D
        }
    }
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

Or do you want something else?

Comment: What are left and width? I think it goes like that but my variable players is an array with the names of the players.

Comment: Then tell me, how do you move the pictures? Can you show me the whole code?